# Why is imaginary part of complex number negative when it is divided?

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers

```
a= 6/5j
print(a)
```

It prints `-1.2j`. Why it is a negative value in Python?

Comment: Your question seems to be related to the maths, not the programming.

Comment: In python, you can be more explicit about the intent of a complex number by using the type as a constructor. `complex(real, imaginary)`, so in your case I believe you intended `complex(0, 6/5j)`.

Comment: What else were you expecting?

Comment: Oh, did you mean `(6/5)*1j` instead of `6/(5j)`?

Answer (score 4):

More of a math question, but the answer is

6/(5j) = 6j/(5jj) = 6j/(-5) = -1.2j

In general, 1/j = j/(jj) = -j

Answer (score 4):

In python, a [complex literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#imaginary-literals) is `(floatnumber | digitpart) ("j" | "J")` with an optional real part in front of it. Therefore in

```
6/5j
```

`5j` is interpreted as a complex literal, which makes the calculation result correct (see other answers). To have a "lonely" j in your calculation, you always need to add a `1` in front of it:

```
6/5*1j
```

This does differ from how e.g. [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%2F5j) would handle the same input.